# Continue Button not moving from Billing address to next section

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I am currently developing a website but have a problem with the create an account page. When you have filled out the billing information, and select the Ship to the Address option and press continue, it doesn't do anything. When you select "Ship to a different address" it will go to the Shipping address pane. The website is still in development, but can't get passed this page.

Comment: Please provide any Javascript errors, PHP errors from the apache logs and Magento errors from the system.log and exception.log so we have more information to go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using magento 1.6 version and when i checked your site and goes to checkout page it gives me javascript error like `countryRegions` is not defined.

[image]

So there must be missing `countryRegions` JSON array.

To solve that open

app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\checkout\onepage.phtml

add these line

```
<script type="text/javascript">countryRegions = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?></script>
```

Or

Open

app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml

replace with

```
var shippingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('shipping:country_id', 'shipping:region', 'shipping:region_id', countryRegions, undefined, 'shipping:postcode');
```

this one

```
var shippingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('shipping:country_id', 'shipping:region', 'shipping:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'shipping:postcode');
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I can't thank you enough, that worked a treat. Top marks!!

Comment: well glad to hear that it works for you @davidclayfield